# Why is name of one "bubble" of Artemis Shepard?

Tags: artemis

In recently launched book *Artemis* (by Andy Weir), we see that Artemis, the first city on the moon, is made of five huge interconnected spheres called "bubbles". Armstrong Bubble sits in the middle, surrounded by Aldrin, Conrad, Bean, and Shepard.

Well, everyone knows who Armstrong and Aldrin are (first and second man on the moon). [Conrad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pete_Conrad) is the third man to walk on moon. [Bean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Bean) is the fourth man to walk on moon.

But, why is [Shepard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Shepard) so special regarding moon? I expected him to be the fifth man to walk on moon, but he isn't. Yes, I know he is the second man (and, first American) to go into space, but it doesn't make sense to put his name in Artemis if Yuri Gagarin's name isn't there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Shepard), states that Shepard was the fifth man to walk on the moon, as the commander of Apollo 14

> At age 47, he became the fifth and oldest person to walk on the Moon, and the only one of the Mercury Seven astronauts to do so. During the mission, he hit two golf balls on the lunar surface.

Comment: Oh, I missed that. Someone should put this important information in the beginning.

Comment: no problem - sometimes the wall of text means we miss things, I know I do :)